# Can I download MP3, MP4, WAV files to the iPhone and play them from Files?

Tags: iphone, mp3, mp4

I have private MP3, MP4 and WAV files that are not available via the itunes store, as they are private.

I use Linux, so how can I download them from a web server, save them on the iPhone, manage them and play them? Is the Files app the means of doing that?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't use iTunes/Music to sync your local music to your phone? That is what syncing the phone is for, among other things.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a Mac. I use Linux.

Comment: That is critical data that I have no put in your question. It *might* be easiest to run iTunes in a Windows VM.

Comment: you can use some File Manager app (other than Files app)

Comment: I think you should be able to import audio files directly into "Music" on your iPhone, without any syncing to another device or using iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

If you use iCloud you can use the website https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/ and upload your files to the Documents folder. They will then appear in the Files app on your iPhone, and any media supported by iOS should be playable from there.

As everyone gets 5GB free anyway with their Apple ID, this is probably the most painless way to transfer files.

Note, you can't transfer music into the Music app from there. That only works via iTunes (yes, there are some 3rd party apps, but iTunes officially).

Files will also work with a Samba server on a local LAN, straightforward to setup with a Linux machine.

Comment: Oh, iCloud's no good for me. These are personal, private MP3 and MP4 files, and I don't want Apple to get access to them.

Comment: @ruminater You should have mentioned that. I was going to propose you to use Google Drive but I'm guessing you won't be interested. Also, according to the question only and not your comment here, the answer perfectly answers the question. And who do you think made Files app?